# Digits sums and sum of power

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $D(x,v)$ be the function defined as, sum of digits of $v$ in base $x$.

*Example:* $D(2,7)=3$

> **Can it be shown that**
>
> If
>   $$  n_0^m+n_1^m+\cdots+n_u^m =a^b, $$
>   where $n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_u,m,u,a$ and $b$ are positive integers with $m>1$ , then $\gcd(n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_u,a)\mid \gcd(D(a+1,n_0^{m}),D(a+1,n_1^{m}),\ldots,D(a+1,n_u^{m})$ ?

**Example**

Let $3^3+24^3+45^3=18^4$

So  $D(19,3^3)=9,D(19,24^3)=18,D(19,45^3)=27$

See $\gcd(3,24,45,18)\mid\gcd(D(19,3^3),D(19,24^3),D(19,45^3))$

> **Update** claim
>
> > If
> >     $$  n_0^{m_0}+n_1^{m_1}+\cdots+n_u^{m_u} =a^b, $$
> >     where $n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_u,m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_u,a,b$ and $u$ are positive integers with $\{m_0,m_1,\ldots,m_u\}>1$ , then $\gcd(n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_u,a)\mid \gcd(D(a+1,n_0^{m_0}),D(a+1,n_1^{m_1}),\ldots,D(a+1,n_u^{m_u})$ ?

*Example*

Let $63^2+6^6=225^2$

So  $D(226,63^2)=144,D(226,6^6)=306$

See $\gcd(63,6,225)\mid\gcd(D(226,63^2),D(226,6^6))$

---

Python programme to calculate $D$ function.

```
    n1=19
    n2=45**3
    rem_array = []
    while n2 != 0:
        mod = n2%n1
        if mod != 0:
          rem = mod
          n2 = n2 - rem
          rem_array.append(round(rem))
          n2=n2/n1
        else:
            n2 = n2/n1
            rem_array.append(0)
    print(rem_array[::-1])
    print("D(n1,n2)=",sum(rem_array))
```

Comment: Just a comment on your writing style: using excessive mathematical formulas makes it much harder for readers to understand what you’re saying. It’s not “incorrect”, just as it wouldn’t be incorrect to use literary language on a day-to-day basis. But it makes effective communication (especially on this site) much harder.

Comment: Its not clear to me what you're asking though some possibly relevant identities you could make use of are that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any integers $a\neq b$ we have $\small\gcd\left(\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b},a-b\right)=\gcd(n\gcd(a,b)^{n-1},a-b)$ also for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and any integer $b\geq 2$ if $d_n=\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{b^n}}\right\rfloor-b\left\lfloor{\frac{x}{b^{n+1}}}\right\rfloor$ then  $\small\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}(0\leq d_n\leq b-1)$ and $x=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}d_nb^n$.

Comment: Also many identities involving sums of digits in certain bases and divisibility properties come from the periodicity of modular exponentiation i.e. the base powers scaling each digit are eventually periodic in their exponents modulo any positive integer.

Comment: Ultimately, isn't this just the same rule that leads multiples of $3$ and $9$ to have digit sums that are multiples of $3$ and $9$, respectively, in base $10$? A multiple of $n$ written in base $b$ will have a digit sum a multiple of $n$ if $b\equiv1\pmod{n}$.

Comment: @nickgard It seems but i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any base $b$, we can see that a number is of the form $a=\sum d_ib^i$ for digits $d_i$. We also know that $b^i \equiv 1 \pmod{b-1}$. Thus, we can conclude that in base $b$, the sum of the digits of a number $a$ leaves the same remainder as $a$, when divided by $b-1$. In notation-
$$a \equiv D(b,a) \pmod{b-1}$$
If we have $g=\gcd(n_0,n_1,\ldots,n_u,a)$, then we can see that $g \mid n_i^{m_i}$. We also know $$D(a+1,n_i^{m_i}) \equiv n_i^{m_i} \pmod{a} \implies g \mid D(a+1,n_i^{m_i})$$
because $g$ divides both $n_i^{m_i}$ and $a$. Since $g$ divides all of $D(a+1,n_i^{m_i})$, it divides their greatest common divisor. This concludes the proof.